# Create node from custom form using ajax

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

How do I add a node from a custom form using ajax? I want it to be submitted in the backend. How will it be if there are custom fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in drupal you can create node using node_save function as below

```
$node = new StdClass();//creating a bare node
$node->type = 'answer';//giving it type
$node->status = 1;//give it a published staus
$node->title = "Step up to the FLava";//gives title
$node->body = "Body Body body"; //gives body

node_save($node);
//save it and give it the rest of the attributes`
```

Comment: For custom fields, you just add them in the node before saving it :
    $node->field_my_custom_field['und'][0]['value'] = 'my value';